# How to retrieve data from myschoolmenus.com api?

Tags: curl, http-headers

I've been trying to access school menu data from the MySchoolMenus.com API in order to create an Alexa app but have encountered issues.

Initial API Call Identification:

Initially identified an API call using Chrome's Developer Tools: https://myschoolmenus.com/api/public/menus?site=13428&expire=1706671844235.
The expire parameter appeared to be a dynamically generated timestamp.
Testing with curl:

Attempted a curl request using the identified URL.
Received a response indicating a "Bad request."
Reverse Engineering expire Parameter:

Converted the expire timestamp to a human-readable date, which correlated with the time of my API call.
Tried creating a timestamp for one day in the future to test with curl, but continued to receive "Bad request."
404 Not Found Error:

Modified the API call based on a previous Stack Overflow post: [https://www.myschoolmenus.com/api/v1/public/menu/{menu_id}](https://www.myschoolmenus.com/api/v1/public/menu/%7Bmenu_id%7D) with x-district header.
Used my school's specific menu, organization, and site IDs.
The response was a 404 error with a "Not Found" HTML page.
I'm not sure what the correct API endpoint or headers should be. Any guidance on how to properly access the MySchoolMenus.com API would be greatly appreciated.